# how to solve geolocation api error in python

Tags: python, geolocation

i have written a python geolocation code to locate a address ,but displays  an error

```
geolocation.exceptions.ApiClientException: Request was denied
```

My python code is:

```
from geolocation.main import GoogleMaps
from geolocation.distance_matrix.client import DistanceMatrixApiClient

address="New York City Wall Street 12"

google_maps=GoogleMaps(api_key='your_google_map_key')

location=google_maps.search(location=address)
print(location.all())
my_location=location.first()

print(my_location.city) 
print(my_location.route) 
print(my_location.street_number)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414546/raise-apiclientexceptionmessage-geolocation-exceptions-apiclientexception-req

Answer (score 1):

I guess you haven't got an API key?

In the code you wrote:

> google_maps=GoogleMaps(api_key='your_google_map_key')

But instead of

> 'your_google_map_key'

You should get your own API key, which you can do by following this link.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/get-api-key

Without the API Key, your request will be denied.

Hopefully this solves the problem :)